# Is there any way to make a TableView "float" over other elements in TornadoFX

Tags: java, kotlin, javafx, tornadofx

I have a textfield with which i search through a database, and i display that data in a TableView in a dropdown fashion (not using a dropdown since I'd like to display multiple properties in a row). When I use the TableView, it displaces all of the other fields below it.

Is there any way to make that TableView "float" over the other fields?

Maybe put it in a special fragment which I might call, or some other Component which might enable this kind of functionality if TableView and stylesheet don't give that natively.

Comment: Just use a layout pane that allows that to happen (e.g. `Pane` or `StackPane`, etc, or put it in a `PopupControl`, depending on the exact functionality you want.

Comment: I'm a bit late, but thanks, i made a custom solution with PopUpControl, and Skin, and etc.  I used ControlsFX Autocomplete class, and remade a Kotlin version of it, just with a TableView instead of a ListView, also added some other properties that it needed like controller, Unit Code, etc etc.